# Video in Flash Canvas causes problems in Chrome

Tags: html, video, createjs, easeljs

I'm having some trouble with video (Flash Canvas / Createjs->Easeljs) when dealing with Google Chrome. In the lower part of the video, reoccurring pixels appears.

[image]

This is the code, loading the movie:

```
this.video = document.createElement('video');
this.video.src = stageroot.server+"/"+stageroot.campaign+"/"+stageroot.portal+"/"+stageroot.dimensions+"/"+stageroot.version+"/"+stageroot.campaign+"_loop_"+stageroot.portal+"_"+stageroot.dimensions+"_"+stageroot.version+".mp4";
this.video.preload = true;
this.video.class = "setBlock";
this.video.name = "myVideo";
this.video.id = "myVideo";
this.video.autoplay = true; 
this.video.controls = false;
this.video.loop = true;
this.video.muted = true;

this.Video = new createjs.Bitmap(this.video);
this.Video.addEventListener("added", loaded);
this.loop_mc.loopfilm_mc.addChild(this.Video);
```

When creating a normal video-tag using plain HTML, it doesn't occur.

I've looked for a solution; re-encoded the film several times (in case it was an encoding issue) as well as testing a number of other sources. A fellow coder mentioned in forum under a similar topic, that it was a known problem and that the style "display: block" should be added. However, any styling applied to **this.video** is ignored. I tried add the styling to **this.video** as well as defining a style, called "setBlock" in the HTML document.

```
this.video.style.display = "block";
```

In order to make it more obvious if the styling was set properly, I temporarily changed "display: block" with "width: 100px" - ***but the styling is completely ignored.***

When doing a console.log on **this.video**, it presents this:

```
<video src="https://***myserver***/inferno/generic/930x180/v1/inferno_loop_generic_930x180_v1.mp4" preload="true" id="myVideo" autoplay="" loop="" style="width:100px;"></video>
```

I'm very puzzled about this. I haven't yet tried to inject a plain HTMl5 video tag - but under all circumstances, it just annoys me that I cannot seem to come up with a Createjs-solution.

Any suggestions - solutions, alternative approaches etc. - will be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, I did a workaround, testing for Chrome - and if true, then I played a webm-version / false, I played the mp4-version. However, the question still stands in order to save time and minimize mistakes.

Comment: I've tried to isolate the problem even more - and it seems, it's only users with a nVidia GPU who are affected.